# Getting 403 Forbbiden error with Google cloud

Tags: c++, cloud, google-cloud-storage

We are getting "Forbidden error(403)" while trying to upload data on Google cloud when there is a time skew on my machine i.e. my machine clock is not synchronized/updated with the NTP server.

Why does Google not return the proper error information?

Comment: How are you performing the upload and authenticating? Are you using gsutil? The web UI? A custom C++ program? Are you authenticating with 2-step OAuth 2 or with a service account? Is your clock skewed by a few seconds or a few years?

Comment: We are using C++ program which uses google API v1.0 to connect and upload data to google cloud. For authentication we are using Signature identifier(GOOG1) and user identifier i.e access key.

Comment: Is this a new project? If so, have you enabled API 1.0 access? By default, all new projects are only accesible with the 2.0 API. If not, see https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/apiversion1#enabling for instructions.

Comment: This is not a new project. All uploads, downloads and other cloud operations are working fine. Only in case of time skew , we were not getting the proper error information.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you are setting the "Date" field incorrectly. All (signed) API v1.0 requests must include a "Date" header, and that header must be part of the signature for the request. The Date field must be within 15 minutes of the real clock time that Google's servers receive your request. If your clock is more than 15 minutes skewed, your signed requests will be rejected.

For more, please see the v1.0 API documentation here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/developer-guidev1#authentication under the CanonicalHeaders section.

This is also the case with S3. See here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#04

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since the clock on my system was skewed it must be more than 15 mins skewed, but why the google is not returning proper error instead of rejecting the request. With amazon we get proper error.

Comment: The error I would expect you to see is <Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the server's time is too large.</Message><Date>(the time you specified)</Date></Error>. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: No,we are just getting "Forbidden error"(HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden)

Comment: 403 is the correct code for a time difference error, but the messaging appears in the body as an XML document. Is it possible your C++ app is not exposing this message?

Comment: We are not getting the xml document. The same app is giving the correct message with amazon. Does google cloud sends the xml document with v1.0 too?

Comment: Just tried it again: `curl -H "Host: storage.googleapis.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: identity" -H "Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 22:29:40 GMT" -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "x-goog-api-version: 1" -H "Authorization: GOOG1 SIGNATURE" -H 'User-Agent: curl' 'https://storage.googleapis.com/quick-auth-test/?delimiter=/'  `

produces:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the server's time is too large.</Message><Date>Fri, 26 Jul 2013 22:29:40</Date></Error>`

Comment: Here is the wireshark output
HEAD /zcb_1369171715_000000000000000047602_g1r_us/.attribute HTTP/1.1
Host: commondatastorage.googleapis.com
Accept: */*
Authorization: GOOG1 .......x-goog-api-version: 1
x-goog-project-id: 518041171838
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 21:49:28 GMT

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 7 2013 11:30:13 (1370629813)
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 218
Date: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 19:45:13 GMT
Expires: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 19:45:13 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0

Comment: Ahah! You're making a HEAD request! Per the HTTP spec, I don't believe HEAD requests return message bodies. If you were trying to retrieve the contents of the object via GET, you'd likely see this error. I suspect that there is no good way to return a more specific error message here.

Comment: It's funny some of the things providers worry about.... like... making sure my *time* is correct... not... that I have the right credentials and all, just that... the time is correct... At any rate, after running `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` those 403's turned back into 200's. :D